# Radial Tree - Root node issue

Tags: d3.js

I am drawing a radial tree using d3 v4. 
I have 3 buttons for loading the data for 3 different years. 
When I click the button the first time, the root changes from United States to some other value (which is a child of United States).
On further clicks(after say, about 20 clicks), the value again changes from United states to some other child.

Could anyone help me with this. Please find below the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #999;
  stroke: steelblue; 
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: #e6f5c9;//#f03b20; //#c6dbef;
  //stroke: #ccc;
  stroke: #e6f5c9;//#f03b20;
  //stroke-width: 5.5px;

.ticks {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.track,
.track-inset,
.track-overlay {
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.track {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: 0.3;
  stroke-width: 10px;
}

.track-inset {
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 8px;
}

.track-overlay {
  pointer-events: stroke;
  stroke-width: 50px;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.handle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke-width: 1.25px;
}  

</style>
<body>
<div id="collapseButton">
    <input name="collapseButton" 
           type="button" 
           value="Collapse All Nodes" 
           onclick="updateData()" />
</div>
<div id="year_2013">
    <input name="2013Data" 
           type="button" 
           value="Wait times for 2013" 
           onclick="updateData2013()" />
</div>
<div id="year_2014">
    <input name="2014Data" 
           type="button" 
           value="Wait times for 2014" 
           onclick="updateData2014()" />
</div>
<div id="year_2015">
    <input name="2015Data" 
           type="button" 
           value="Wait times for 2015" 
           onclick="updateData2015()" />
</div>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var duration=1500, delay = 3000;


    var width = 960,
    height = 1000,
    margin = {top:20,bottom:20,right:20,left:20};
    duration = 750;

    var buttonPressed = "2013";

    var nodes,links;
    var i = 0;


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width",width)
                .attr("height",height);

    var g = svg.append("g")
                //.attr("transform","translate(100,400)");
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");
    createSvg2();
    //var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 + 40) + "," + (height / 2 + 90) + ")");

    //var button = g.selectAll("button");
    //console.log(button);

    //g.append("button");

    function connector(d) {
            return "M" + project(d.x, d.y)
                 + "C" + project(d.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
                 + " " + project(d.parent.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
                 + " " + project(d.parent.x, d.parent.y);
    }

    var tree,
        root;

    var nodeSvg, linkSvg, nodeEnter, linkEnter;
    //updateData2013();
    initialFunction();
    function initialFunction()
    {
        tree = d3.tree()
        //.size([360,250]);
        //.size([150,50]),
        .size([150,100]);

        function collapse(d) 
        {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        }

    d3.json("treeData.json",function(error,treeData){
        if(error) throw error;

        root = d3.hierarchy(treeData,function(d){
            return d.children;
        });
        console.log("Data is: \n");
        root.each(function (d) {
                d.name = d.data.name; //transferring name to a name variable
                d.id = i; //Assigning numerical Ids
                i += i;
        });

        root.x0 = height / 2;
            root.y0 = 0;

        //root.children.forEach(collapse);
        update(root);
    });
    }



function update(source) {

    nodes = tree(root).descendants();
    links = nodes.slice(1);
    var nodeUpdate;
    var nodeExit;

// To maintain the depth of the tree always, comment for self arranging tree
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; }); // 180

    nodeSvg = g.selectAll(".node")
                .data(nodes,function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });


    var nodeEnter = nodeSvg.enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + project(d.x, d.y) + ")"; })
                    .on("click",click);
                    //.on("mouseover", function(d) { return "minu"; });


    nodeEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("r", function(d){ return 5;})
            .style("fill", color);


    nodeEnter.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".31em")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
            //.style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 === !d.children ? "start" : "end"; })
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "start" : "start"; })
            //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x < 180 ? d.x - 40 : d.x + 40) + ")"; })
            .attr("transform",function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? ("translate(20,0)") : ("translate(0,0)"); }) // straight to right
            //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x < 180 ? d.x - 90 : d.x + 90) + ")"; })
            //.attr("transform",function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? ("translate(20,0)") : ("translate(0,0)"); })
            .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

            // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = nodeSvg.merge(nodeEnter).transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + project(d.x, d.y) + ")"; });


    nodeSvg.select("circle")
      .style("fill", color);


    nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = nodeSvg.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; }) //for the animation to either go off there itself or come to centre
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
            d.x0 = d.x;
            d.y0 = d.y;
    });


    linkSvg = g.selectAll(".link")
                    .data(links, function(link) { var id = link.id + '->' + link.parent.id; return id; });


    // Transition links to their new position.
    linkSvg.transition()
           .duration(duration);
           // .attr('d', connector);

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    linkEnter = linkSvg.enter().insert('path', 'g')
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .attr("d", function (d) {
                        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0, parent: {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}};
                        return connector(o);
                    })
                    .style("fill",pathColor)
                    .style("stroke",pathColor)
                    .style("stroke-width","1.5px");



    // Transition links to their new position.
    linkSvg.merge(linkEnter).transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", connector);


    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    linkSvg.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", function (d) {
                        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y, parent: {x: source.x, y: source.y}};
                        return connector(o);
                    })
                    .remove();



}
//timeSlider();
function showClock(d)
{
    console.log("Show Clock");
    console.log(project(d.x,d.y));

}

function click(d) {

  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {

    d.children = d._children;
    if(d.children == null)
    {
        showClock(d);
    }
    d._children = null;


  }
  update(d);
}

function updateData2013()
{
    buttonPressed = "2013";
    initialFunction();
    console.log("2013 Data");
    //setTimeout(updateData2014, duration + delay);

}

function updateData2014()
{
    buttonPressed = "2014";
    initialFunction();
    console.log("2014 Data");
    //setTimeout(updateData2015, duration + delay);
}

function updateData2015()
{
    buttonPressed = "2015";
    initialFunction();
    console.log("2015 Data");
    //setTimeout(updateData2013, duration + delay);
}

function pathColor(d)
{
//['#1b9e77','#d95f02','#7570b3','#e7298a','#66a61e','#e6ab02']
    if(buttonPressed == "2013")
    {
        if(d.data.time_2013 >= 5 && d.data.time_2013 <= 8)
        {
            return "#1b9e77";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2013 > 8 && d.data.time_2013 <= 11)
        {
            return "#d95f02";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2013 > 11 && d.data.time_2013 <= 14)
        {
            return "#7570b3";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2013 > 14 && d.data.time_2013 <= 17)
        {
            return "#e7298a";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2013 > 17 && d.data.time_2013 <= 21)
        {
            return "#66a61e";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2013 > 21 && d.data.time_2013 <= 24)
        {
            return "#e6ab02";
        }
    }
    else if(buttonPressed == "2014")
    {
        if(d.data.time_2014 >= 5 && d.data.time_2014 <= 8)
        {
            return "#1b9e77";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2014 > 8 && d.data.time_2014 <= 11)
        {
            return "#d95f02";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2014 > 11 && d.data.time_2014 <= 14)
        {
            return "#7570b3";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2014 > 14 && d.data.time_2014 <= 17)
        {
            return "#e7298a";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2014 > 17 && d.data.time_2014 <= 21)
        {
            return "#66a61e";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2014 > 21 && d.data.time_2014 <= 24)
        {
            return "#e6ab02";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(d.data.time_2015 >= 5 && d.data.time_2015 <= 8)
        {
            return "#1b9e77";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2015 > 8 && d.data.time_2015 <= 11)
        {
            return "#d95f02";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2015 > 11 && d.data.time_2015 <= 14)
        {
            return "#7570b3";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2015 > 14 && d.data.time_2015 <= 17)
        {
            return "#e7298a";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2015 > 17 && d.data.time_2015 <= 21)
        {
            return "#66a61e";
        }
        else if(d.data.time_2015 > 21 && d.data.time_2015 <= 24)
        {
            return "#e6ab02";
        }
    }
}

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package 
      : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
      : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node 
}

function project(x, y) {
  var angle = (x - 90) / 180 * Math.PI, radius = y;
  return [radius * Math.cos(angle), radius * Math.sin(angle)];
}

function updateData()
{
    console.log("Button is clicked");
    //toggleAll(root.children);
    root.children.forEach(toggleAll);

}

function toggleAll(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
        compressNodes(d);
    }
}

function compressNodes(d) {
    if(d==root)
    {
    }
    else{
        console.log("inside d.children");
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
    update(d);
    //simulation.restart();
    }


}
function createSvg2()
{
    var width1 = 10,
    height1 = 1000;

    var svg2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width",width)
                .attr("height",height);

    svg2.append("circle")
    .attr("r",2.5)
    .attr("transform","translate(" + width1/2 + "," + height1/4 + ")")
    .attr("fill","red");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Json:

```
{
  "name": "United States",
  "children": [
    {
        "name": "Ohio",
        "children":[
        {   "name" : "Cincinnati Northern Kentucky Intl", "code" : "CVG" , "time_2013": 15.01, "time_2014": 13.22, "time_2015": 13.81}
      ]
    },
    {
        "name": "California",
        "children":[
        {"name": "San Francisco", "code" : "" , "time_2013":15, "time_2014": 15.01, "time_2015": 15.01},
        {"name": "San Jose", "code" : "" , "time_2013":25, "time_2014": 15.01, "time_2015": 15.01},
        {"name": "Los Angeles", "code" : "" , "time_2013":17, "time_2014": 15.01, "time_2015": 15.01}
        ]
    },
    { 
      "name": "Illinois",
      "children":[
      { "name" : "Chicago Ohare Intl",  "code" : "ORD" , "time_2013": 18.58, "time_2014": 14.37, "time_2015": 14.32},
      { "name" : "Chicago Midway Intl",  "code" : "MDW" , "time_2013": 11.19 , "time_2014": 14.37, "time_2015": 7.31}
      ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Colorado",
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Denver Intl", "code" : "DEN" , "time_2013": 13.31, "time_2014": 13.33, "time_2015": 12.51}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Florida",
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Florida airport", "code" : "" , "time_2013": 13.31, "time_2014": 13.33, "time_2015": 12.51}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Georgia",
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta Intl", "code" : "ATL" , "time_2013": 10.08, "time_2014": 10.00, "time_2015": 10.81}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Kentucky", 
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Kentucy airport", "code" : "KEN" , "time_2013": 13.31, "time_2014": 13.33, "time_2015": 12.51}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Massachussets",  
        "children" : [
        {"name": "General Edward Lawrence Logan Intl", "code" : "BOS" , "time_2013": 19.86, "time_2014": 19.24, "time_2015": 17.22}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Michigan", 
        "children" : [
        {"name" : "Detroit Metro Wayne Co", "code" : "DTW" , "time_2013":15.71, "time_2014": 15.55, "time_2015": 15.01}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Minnesota",  
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Minnesota airport", "code" : "DEN" , "time_2013": 13.31, "time_2014": 13.33, "time_2015": 12.51}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Missouri", 
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Missouri airport", "code" : "DEN" , "time_2013": 13.31, "time_2014": 13.33, "time_2015": 12.51}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "North Carolina",  
        "children" : [
        {"name" : "Charlotte Douglas Intl","code" : "CLT" , "time_2013": 13.75 , "time_2014": 12.73, "time_2015": 9.21}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Nevada",
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Nevada airport", "code" : "DEN" , "time_2013": 13.31, "time_2014": 13.33, "time_2015": 12.51}
        ]
    },
    { 
        "name": "Newyork",  
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Newyork airport", "code" : "DEN" , "time_2013": 13.31, "time_2014": 13.33, "time_2015": 12.51}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Oregon", 
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Oregon airprot", "code" : "OR" , "time_2013": 13.31, "time_2014": 13.33, "time_2015": 12.51}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Pennsylvania",
        "children": [
        { "name" : "Pensylvania Airport", "code" : "PEN" , "time_2013" : 9.18, "time_2014": 7.7, "time_2015": 9.31}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Mary Land",
        "children": [
        { "name" : "Baltimore Washington Intl", "code" : "BWI" , "time_2013" : 9.18, "time_2014": 7.7, "time_2015": 9.31}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Hawaii",
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Hawaiiiiiii" , "code" : "HAW" , "time_2013": 21.33, "time_2014": 11.98, "time_2015": 13.47}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Texas",
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Dallas Fort Worth Intl" , "code" : "DFW" , "time_2013": 21.33, "time_2014": 11.98, "time_2015": 13.47},
        { "name": "Houston" , "code" : "" , "time_2013": 13, "time_2014": 15.01, "time_2015": 15.01},
        { "name": "Austin Bergstrom Intl" , "code" : "AUS" , "time_2013": 13.52, "time_2014": 16.38, "time_2015": 13.29}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Utah",  
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Utah Airport", "code" : "DEN" , "time_2013": 13.31, "time_2014": 13.33, "time_2015": 12.51}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Virginia",  
        "children" : [
        { "name": "Virginia Airport", "code" : "DEN" , "time_2013": 13.31, "time_2014": 13.33, "time_2015": 12.51}
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is changing the key in your `data` function from this:

```
nodeSvg = g.selectAll(".node")
   .data(nodes,function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
```

To this:

```
nodeSvg = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes,function(d) { return d.id; });
```

Here is a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tMQBMyaWJEtEl9aPoDkQ?p=preview